# Passing a rectangular array to a view file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, arrays, razor

I'm a relative newbie to C#/MVC and I've come across an issue when passing a rectangular array to ViewData (and then trying to display the contents from within a View file).

My array is populated from a database query, and as far as I can see it's coming through fine:

```
Media [
    Images [
        [Id (int), Type (int), File (string), Title (string)],
        [Id (int), Type (int), File (string), Title (string)],
        [Id (int), Type (int), File (string), Title (string)]
    ]
    Videos [
        [Id (int), Type (int), File (string), Title (string)],
        [Id (int), Type (int), File (string), Title (string)]
    ]
]
```

I'm assigning each half of the main array (Images and Videos) to a separate ViewData object in the Controller:

```
ViewData["Images"] = Media.Images.ToArray();
ViewData["Videos"] = Media.Videos.ToArray();
```

The View knows that these objects are there, but I can't seem to figure out how to loop through each array and access each individual index (Id, Type, File, Title) from within the View and add each piece to the View's HTML code.

One option would be to construct the HTML in the controller, but I really want to avoid that.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

EDIT: Here's the fix, thanks to everyone for prodding me down the right track :)

Controller:

```
ViewBag.Images = Media.Images;
```

Web.Config:

```
<namespaces>
    <add namespace="Path.to.Models" />
    ...
</namespaces>
```

View:

```
str_code = "<ul>";

foreach (Media image in ViewBag.Images)
{
    str_code += "<li>" + image.Title + "</li>";   
}

str_code += "</ul>";

Response.Write(str_code);
```

Comment: what does your view look right now? Have you considered using a List or IQueryable vs using Array in the View.

Comment: At the moment the view is a real mess - I'm trying everything I can think of to loop though each object, but no luck so far. I'm not tied to using arrays - I just need to be able to loop through each object and access the individual properties.

Comment: On your view cast ViewData["Images"] to something which implemets IEnumerable. For example Video[] if you have Video class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `Media.Images.ToArray();` gives you an array of `MyImage` objects.

**MyImage**

```
public class MyImage
{
    public int Id       { get; set; }
    public int Type     { get; set; }
    public string File  { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Then the Razor code:

```
@foreach (MyImage image in ViewData["Images"])
{
    <p>@image.Id</p>
    <p>@image.Type</p>

     ...
}
```

Alternatively you can use the dynamic property `ViewBag` available in your controller:

```
ViewBag.Images = Media.Images.ToArray();
```

Then:

```
@foreach (MyImage image in ViewBag.Images)
{
    <p>@image.Id</p>
    <p>@image.Type</p>

     ...
}
```

Comment: This won't work as ViewData[] returns doesn't return IEnumerable. You should cast it.

Comment: Haven't tested using `ViewData` but I assume it just works because during runtime it knows `ViewData["Images"]`contains an array. He can also try using `ViewBag` if that fails.

Comment: The same for ViewBag. I think both options are ok but need to update foreach (MyImage image in ViewData["Images"]) to foreach (MyImage image in (MyImage[])ViewData["Images"]) or to foreach (MyImage image in (MyImage[])ViewBag.Images) :)

Comment: I'm trying the ViewBag approach; my Model has a class of MyImage (with Id, Title, etc.) but the View can't access it. I've tried adding @model path.to.MyImage above the loop, but the compiler says "The type or namespace name 'MyImage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"... Gah!

Comment: @petro.sidlovskyy Yeah... I think you're definitely right! :) I rarely work with `ViewData`or `ViewBag`. That's why I didn't remember that you must cast the content before using it. I always try to use strongly typed `ViewModel`s. :)

Comment: @MassivePenguin open the web.config file that lies within your `Views` folder and add the complete namespace of the `MyImage`class in the section `<namespaces>`. After that, close your view file and reopen it. Visual Studio should recognize `MyImage` as a valid type.

Comment: @LenielMacaferi that did it - I can now access the models. Told you I was new at this! I've used this in the controller: 
ViewBag.Images = Media.Images;

and this in the View: 
foreach (MyImage image in ViewBag.Images)
    {
        str_code += "<li>" + image.Title + "</li>";   
    }

Comment: @MassivePenguin Nice... :) I'm glad I could help.